# How can I have two versions of Chart.js in the same HTML file?

Tags: html, chart.js

How to use two different versions of `chart.js` in the same HTML file.

I want to have two different graphs from `chart.js` in one file, but they seem to be overlapping on top of each other. How can I have them both separately?

I have tried using `div` tags to have them on different parts of the page.

Comment: Do you actually want to use different versions of `chart.js` or just two different graphs in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you have used the same "id" for both canvases. You could try something like this:

```
<h1>
Chart 1
</h1>

<div>
  <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
</div>

<h1>
Chart 2
</h1>

<div>
  <canvas id="chart2"></canvas>
</div>
```

The code for the charts - note how the first chart uses "chart1" and the second chart uses "chart2". If both charts use "chart1" then the second chart will be drawn on top of the first chart in the same canvas.

```
new Chart(document.getElementById('chart1'), {
  type: 'line',
  options: {
    responsive: true,
  },
  data: {
    label: [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'First Dataset1',
      data: [61, 44, 35, 33, 29]
    }]
  }
});
new Chart(document.getElementById('chart2'), {
  type: 'bar',
  options: {
    responsive: true,
  },
  data: {
    labels: [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Second Dataset',
      data: [19, 17, 16, 13, 9]
    }]
  }
});
```

Link to working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hdahle/vtnc49pq/